# Load array in Bash from its name passed as argument

Tags: arrays, bash, argument-passing

Is there's a way in Bash to pass at `myFun` something like `ARRAY` and in `myFun` print the array elements like below?

```
myFun {
   echo ${$1[1]}
   ...
}

ARRAY=( first second last )
myFun "ARRAY"
```

I tried and Bash return bad substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by

```
myFun () {
    tmp=$1[@]
    array=("${!tmp}")

    for i in "${array[@]}" ; do
        echo "$i"
    done

}
ARRAY=( 1 2 3 4 5 )
myFun ARRAY
```

Comment: bash array syntax is ... "myFun" indeed.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is read-only access; `array` is a copy of the original.